# Reshaping cell array in matlab - k*MxN to M x k*N

Tags: matlab, reshape, cell-array

I have a k * MxN cell array that I want to reshape into a M x k * N array. But I want to do this blockwise so that the row structure is preserved.

```
A B C         -->        A B C G H I M N O
D E F                    D E F J K L P Q R
G H I   
J K L
M N O
P Q R
```

Is there a possibility without any loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of [`reshape`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html). This approach works for *numeric arrays* or for *cell arrays*.

Let `A` denote your array. Then, the desired result is

```
B = reshape(permute(reshape(A.',N,M,[]),[2 1 3]),M,[]);
```

Or, as noted by Divakar, you can save the transpose, which will reduce running time:

```
B = reshape(permute(reshape(A,M,k,[]),[1 3 2]),M,[]);
```

For example,

```
A = [ 5     9     2
      5     8     4
      5     0     4
      5     5     7
      7     6     3
      8     5     0
      8     7     5
      3     0     5 ];
M = 2;
N = size(A,2);
k = size(A,1)/M;
```

gives

```
B =
     5     9     2     5     0     4     7     6     3     8     7     5
     5     8     4     5     5     7     8     5     0     3     0     5
```

Comment: Save one transpose - `reshape(permute(reshape(A,k,size(A,1)/k,[]),[1 3 2]),k,[])`

Comment: Oh by the way, my `k` would be `2`, that it assumes to "cut" after every `k` rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you matrix is small, then this should work,

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i) A(2*i-1:2*i,:),1:3,'UniformOutput',0))
```

however performance may be better with a more simple loop, especially for a larger matrix.